# Json file not found exception on eclipse running on mac. Works fine on Windows

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, gradle

I have written a java code to get the JSON path string from URI, and URI from URL. when I run the code on Windows, it works fine but when I run the same code on Mac it gives Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException

To be precise this is the error I am getting:
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/Working Directory/Work/Work-Prof/CLineProject/CLINE/bin/main/org/cline/contract/purchases/Customer.json (No such file or directory)

But when I follow this path, the file is residing at the exact location

It is already working on Windows OS but not on the MacOS Mojave

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
public static String CUSTOMER_JSON = initializeVariables("Customer.json");
}
private static String initializeVariables (String _fileName) {
    //Getting the file from the resources folder;
    URL conversionVariable = Main.class.getResource(_fileName);
    String convertedVariable = "", newName = "";
    try
    {
        //Converting URL to URI
        URI uri = conversionVariable.toURI();
        //type-casting the URI to a string
        convertedVariable = uri.toString();
        //replacing "%20" with a white space
        newName = convertedVariable.replaceAll("%20", " ");

    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newName;
}
```

It should give me the path of the JSON file to be used to fetch the entries from. But it is throwing the above-mentioned examples

Comment: macOS is case sensitive. Does your code match the exact cases used for your file's name on disk?

Comment: Yes. It matched exactly the same.

Comment: That file URL would be interpreted as absolute for the entire system. Under Macintosh HD, do you really intend to have a "Working Directory" directory?

Comment: "Working Directory" is not mandatory, but it is not working even on put the project on the main drive